# Azure function (backed by container) runs two docker images, even when scaling is set to 1

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

I am running a Azure Function app, with the below scaling configuration.

[image]

Now when I go to logs I see the container being run twice; I intend to run it only once, what am I missing here please.

2021-05-17T16:29:35.273Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:50c6bb3b42cbec735f27dbfdec142b8712ced412a4572e3e8b0d994fc40a9f25
2021-05-17T16:29:35.390Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for mymodelcoderegistry01.azurecr.io/mymodelcode-python:latest
2021-05-17T16:29:35.394Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 6 Seconds
2021-05-17T16:29:35.403Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-05-17T16:29:35.404Z INFO  - **docker run -d -p 9590:80 --name** func-mymodelcode-python_1_abbba506 -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=mymodelcoderegistry01.azurecr.io/mymodelcode-python -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=func-mymodelcode-python -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=True -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=func-mymodelcode-python.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=ad45b99e26d7da1f3002a9bb75c206eb8bb8c41e6ef342ff89a36f2fe65e39c0 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 mymodelcoderegistry01.azurecr.io/mymodelcode-python:latest

2021-05-17T16:29:39.601Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-05-17T16:29:39.602Z INFO  - **docker run -d -p 7377:8081 --name** func-mymodelcode-python_1_abbba506_middleware -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=mymodelcoderegistry01.azurecr.io/mymodelcode-python -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=func-mymodelcode-python -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=True -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=func-mymodelcode-python.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=ad45b99e26d7da1f3002a9bb75c206eb8bb8c41e6ef342ff89a36f2fe65e39c0 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/middleware:1.4.5 /Host.ListenUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8081 /Host.DestinationHostUrl=http://334.332.122.2:80 /Host.UseFileLogging=true

Comment: it s looks like these are two different apps: `docker run -d -p 9590:80 --name func-mymodelcode-python_1_abbba506` and `docker run -d -p 7377:8081 --name func-mymodelcode-python_1_abbba506_middleware` ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but the docker image is the same.

Comment: Check this article, it looks like it s an additional container created by the azure function by default: https://hajekj.net/2019/01/21/exploring-app-service-authentication-on-linux/
I googled `appsvc/middleware`